Problema com kapt em um projeto em migração
Estou migrando um projeto mobile de Java para Kotlin, mas estou enfrentando problemas na parte de injeção de dependências. No projeto atual em Java, usamos annotationProcessor, mas essa abordagem não é suportada no Kotlin.
Tentei implementar kapt, mas isso está gerando conflitos com o annotationProcessor, o que impede a migração gradual que estou planejando. Estou migrando uma tela de cada vez e utilizamos anotações como @HiltViewModel, @AndroidEntryPoint, e também o Lombok no projeto Java.
  apply plugin: 'kapt-kotlin'
  kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$androidx.hilt"
  kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$androidx.hiltcompiler"

Tentativas de Resolução: Substituí o annotationProcessor por kapt no build.gradle. Verifiquei as versões das bibliotecas para garantir que são compatíveis. Dificuldades Encontradas: No entanto, o kapt entra em conflito com o annotationProcessor que ainda estou usando em outras partes do projeto. Como estou fazendo a migração gradualmente, não posso remover todas as referências ao Java de uma vez.
O que posso fazer para resolver esses conflitos de injeção de dependências e prosseguir com a migração para Kotlin sem interromper o desenvolvimento do projeto?

Essa pergunta já foi feita, siga as orientações fornecidas na pergunta original, e se precisar comentar, faça nela também.
